# Are fat libraries stripped when building for release in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have a fat (armv7 + i386) library I use for development now. Works fine but now I am concerned if Xcode will strip other architectures (i386) and other configurations (Debug for example) when building for release?

I don't plan to debug this library since it is very old and stable. I just want to use it so I guess I don't need all debug symbols (?), furthermore when building for release I won't even need the i386 since that is for the simulator.

Do I need to set up something in Xcode so it gets stripped or I should better be using a non-fat library? If so how can I control this? :)

This library is about 500KB so I prefer not to put more info than I need.

Comment: You can check any output libraries using the `lipo` command to confirm for yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The library stores separate object files for different architectures (i386, armv7, armv7s etc.). When you build the final app, it will only retrieve the required architectures and only the required object files from the library. The final version for the App Store will certainly not contain any i386.

Regarding *release* and *debug* configuration, it's different. This concept is not known by the library tool. So it cannot store separate debug and release versions. And when building the app, it will take whatever it finds. So to minimize your final app, you'll need to build both the library and the app with release settings.